# Why can't I shut down the avahi-daemon in Fedora Linux?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, fedora, process

I'm using Fedora 16.

I shut down NetworkManager and wpa_supplicant (using service commands), but when I try:

```
sudo service avahi-daemon stop
```

or

```
sudo kill pid
```

it appears again instantly! How can I figure which process is still using avahi?

Comment: If you have time, please upvote and/or pick an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

OP posted this also in the Fedora Forums [here](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=271816).

The solution is to disable the service altogether:

```
systemctl disable avahi-daemon.service
```

That worked for me.

Comment: you should explain how to enable again

Comment: `systemctl enable avahi-daemon` May I suggesties to RTFM?

Comment: Hahaha or you could just post thorough answer for future users. If everyone RTFM then we wouldn't need this site.

Comment: The question was only about *disabling* it. ;-) You're welcome, BTW.

Answer (score 2):

If someone accidentally come across this - in my opinion the problem is that avahi-daemon.socket is bringing the process up again after you kill it (or try to stop it). The idea of sockets is that on the general the service does not need to be started when the system is loaded, but just when someone really needs it. The socket only monitors if someone needs the service and spawns it. I would try stopping the socket first (`systemctl stop avahi-daemon.socket`) and see if after that I can stop the service. See [this](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html) for more information about sockets.

Another thing that might happen is that systemd can respawn a crashed service (or service that got killed). In this case though, `systemctl stop avahi-daemon.service` should work.

Comment: It seems, this also is accurate for disabling avahi-daemon.service - you have to disable also avahi-daemon.socket to prevent avahi waking up.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
systemctl stop avahi-daemon.service
```

should work.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work 
the only way was to disable it and restart

Comment: @Niels could you edit your answer to include a bit more info about how your solution works?

Comment: what gives the command systemctl status avahi-daemon.service ?